# Show that the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^p e^{-x} dx$ converges for every value of $p \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Ok from reading the question, "for every value of $p \in \mathbb{R}$" tells me that there might be some type of discontinuity at some value of $p$. Also from looking at the integrand I kind of get the hint that it might be a comparison test.Looking at the integrand of $e^{-x}$ it converges. However I'm not sure how to  move further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Show that for each $p$ you have 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x^p e^{-x}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=0$$

Deduce that there exists some $A$ such that, for all $x >A$ you have
$$0 \leq x^p e^{-x} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Use the comparison test. If you covered the limit comparison test for integrals you can skip one step above.

**Hint 2** You can calculate 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x^p e^{-x}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{p+2}}{e^x}$$
by applying L'H until the degree in the numerator becomes negative (i.e. $\lfloor p \rfloor +3$ times).

A much faster solution is by oberving that, as long as $p+2 \neq 0$ we have
$$\frac{x^{p+2}}{e^x}= \left( \frac{x}{e^{x/(p+2)}}\right)^{p+2}$$
and the limit inside can be calculated by applying LH once.

If $p+2=0$ then your limit is trivial:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x^p e^{-x}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^x}$$

Comment: Doesn't the limit comparison state that the limit has to be strictly greater than zero?

Comment: @EverOlivares No. Some books do state that version, which is weaker than it needs. But the LC theorem says : If $ 0 \leq f \leq g$ then (a) If $\lim \frac{f}{g} \in [0, \infty)$ and $\int_a^\infty g(t) dt $ is convergent then so is $\int_a^\infty f(t) dt $...

Comment: (b) If $\lim \frac{f}{g} \in (0, \infty]$ and $\int_a^\infty g(t) dt $ is divergent then so is $\int_a^\infty f(t) dt $

Comment: @EverOlivares Whenever when the limit is a positive limit number, the two integrals behave exactly the same way. If the limit is zero or infinity you can only show that the convergence or divergence of the right one implies the convergence or divergence of the other, but conclude nothing in the other case... That's why many books only list the equivalence, since the other cases are a tiny bit more subtle..... Anyhow, this is exactly why I gave a way of avoiding the LCT.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I will look into it further with my professor tomorrow . I am still stuck on the limit. I currently have $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{p+2} e^{-x}$. However this is indeterminate form and applying L'Hospital never stops.

Comment: @EverOlivares Will add a hint for this.

Comment: @EverOlivares See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $m\in \Bbb Z^+$ with $m> p+2.$ For $x\ge 1$ we have $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n/n!>x^m/m!\ge x^{p+2}/m!>0.$$ So $0<x^pe^{-x}<x^p(m!/x^{p+2})=m!/x^2.$

Therefore $$0\le \lim_{r\to \infty}\sup_{\ge r}\int_r^sx^pe^{-x}dx\le \lim_{r\to \infty}\sup_{s\ge r}\int_r^s(m!/x^2)dx=0.$$